# How to get a typo3 form-framework form html via ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, typo3, typo3-extensions

I've got an experimental project at work where I have to check whether or not it is practical to use Typo3 in a headless way, with most of the Typo3 stuff still working.

For the Rest Api I'm using [tx_rest](https://rest.corn.rest/) to expose 
 my endpoints.

In particular I'm currently trying to get the rendered html of a form, which was created by a backend user, with the Typo3 form framework, via ajax.

Does anyone know of a way to retrieve only the rendered html form from Typo3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a way to retrieve only the rendered html form from TYPO3?

Create a new [`PAGE`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html) object with a custom number

```
formPage = PAGE
formPage.typeNum = 765
```

and set

```
formPage.config {
    debug = 0
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    disablePrefixComment = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = none
    admPanel = 0
}
```

to prevent any other output and finally

```
formPage.10 < styles.content.get
```

(or use any other setup to fetch your content, this is just an example, that will output all contents of the current page in colPos 0)

Opening your page with `https://myhost.com/my/path/?type=765` will then render anything on the page without any additional markup, just the output of your page content (e.g. the form plugin, etc.).

Comment: It's quite common to use the variable `page` for the default PAGE with `typeNum = 0`, so it's required to use another variable like `formpage` with `typeNum = 765`.
This avoids also that some simple but annoying faults can happen when any code is copied and pasted for the default page.

Comment: In this answer `styles.content.get` is used to get the content. For unexperienced users it might be important to mention that all content of that page and col is delivered in this case and that it's advisable not to store any other content elements on this page.